# Proving the (Non-)Emptiness condition for Rabin tree automata given by Pnueli and Rosner

Tags: tree-automata

At section 8 of the paper [On the Synthesis of a Reactive Module](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9690/2d95f53358ea23ff401b5198c7315addeb43.pdf), the authors state the following theorem:

> **Proposition 2 (Non-Emptiness Condition)**
>
> Let $A = (Q, \delta, Q_0, \Omega)$ be a tree automaton with
> $\Omega = \{(L_i, U_i) | 1 \leq i \leq m\}$ and $|Q|=n$.
> Then, $T_\omega(A) \neq \emptyset$ if and only if for some finite tree
> $E$ and a run $r=(\nu, E')$ of $A$ on $E$, for every path $\pi$ in $E$,
> there exist an integer $i$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, and strings
> $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}$, such that the following hold:
>
> 1. $x_0 \leq x_1 < \dots < x_n < x_{n+1} \in \pi \cap Ft(E)$.
> 2. For all $l$, $0 < l \leq n+1$, $\nu(x_l) \in U_i$.
> 3. For all $j$, $1 \leq j \leq m$, $\nu[x_1,x_{n+1}] \cap L_j \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \nu[x_0, x_1] \cap L_j \neq \emptyset$.
> 4. $\nu[x_0, x_{n+1}] \cap L_i = \emptyset$.

They do not provide a proof, but add that:

> The following proposition and its proof essentially consist of delicate modifications of the results reported in [[HR72]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/39a2/f25fb7404a7fcaedde1005a5ddb886cd5274.pdf) as theorem 1 and its proof.

---

Since I could not grasp the intuition beyond the third condition, I tried to prove the theorem by myself, with the proof of the mentioned theorem in mind. Proving the 'only if' direction was easy, but I can not come up with a proof for the 'if'.

The idea in [HR72] follows these steps:

- build a mapping $\eta$ from an infinite tree $T$ to the finite tree $E$
- define a run $\overline{r}$ of $A$ on $T$ by means of $\eta$ and the run $r = (\nu, E')$
- show that $\overline{r}$ is an accepting run for $T$, thus $T \in T_\omega(A)$

In [HR72] the conditions are different from those stated by Pnueli and Rosner and I am not able to adapt that proof to this alternative Non-Emptiness condition.

How can I adapt the proof reported in [HR72], in order to prove **Proposition 2**?

Comment: I came up with the proof, it's not difficult, but a bit long. As soon as I have a moment, I'll post the answer here.